# A .htaccess trick to allow only one page from sub-domain to be opened

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

here is the situation and I need a little help with it:
I have a domain `xxxxx.com` and a sub-domain `upload.xxxxx.com` both lead to directory `/www/xxxxx.com/`, but I am using the 2nd domain for file uploading since I am using Cloudflare's services and with the 2nd domain there are no performance optimization and troubles with the upload (I've created cookies that are valid for both domains).

But my point is because I am using only 1 file for that 2nd domain and it `upload.xxxxx.com/upload.php` the same file exist under `xxxxx.com/upload.php` - I am not really good in .htaccess, so how can I make the only page that could be opened from this subdomain to be `upload.php` and all other to redirect to the main domain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end I think it's good for the users who are interested to know:

1. I added a cross domain support for the cookies and added additional domain, upload.*
2. I left the upload.* domain only on redirect rules via Cloudflare (no optimization)
3. Redirected the uploading form to the upload.xxxxx.com/upload.php
4. Made the cookie cross domain based on login so when you login on the main site you're logged in on the upload.* one too.
5. When you submit the form it uploads really fast via upload.* and redirects back to the preview page on the original domain.
6. It handles the errors via cookies from the upload.* to the normal domain

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^upload\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^upload\.php$ /? [NC,L,R]
```